# Foundation CSS fontsize adjustments best practice?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The default font sizes for h1, h2 etc. are very large in Zurb Foundation 4 framework and we need to have page titles and subtitles that are smaller than that.
But what is the best practice here?
Overwrite the css for each of the h1, h2... elements or simply use from h4 and down?

I've read that adjusting the general font-size of the html/body element is not a good solution
http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/

And I'd rather not have to touch each single element in order to shrink the sizes proportionally for all.

But if we use h4 instead of h1 elements, aren't we affecting the SEO of the page?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with changing the `font-size` of a header.

Comment: Just use a font size in `em` or `%` for the headers. Unless you're nesting headers.

Comment: My problem is that if I need to change all the fontsizes, it's not only the headers, but also normal paragraphs, lists etc. And for each media size. Using h4 instead of h1 will affect SEO, correct?

Comment: If you have time on your hands, I'd recommend investing a bit of effort in installing the SCSS (Sass + Compass) version of Foundation, which comes with a settings file full of variables which allow you to quickly customize these basic settings. (Docs -> http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html).

Comment: Other option is to go through the Foundation CSS files and see which statement affects which element and adjust them accordingly.

Comment: The best practice would be to have a new stylesheet that comes below their one that cancels out the default font sizes.

Comment: @dgivoni I don't understand why you need to change all the font sizes if only the header sizes need to change.

Comment: Mr Lister > I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear enough, but i need to reduce all the sizes, also the normal ones.

Comment: Marijke Luttekes> Thanks for the Saas/Compass suggestion, we're going that route and that seems to be the best and in the long run quickest way of adjusting the base sizes etc. of Foundation.

Comment: I would like to urge everyone to please stop using the phrase "best practice". Imagine the subject line of this post without the phrase? The results would be identical I think. Sure perhaps a particular practice is the best we've come up so far, but labeling the idea as "the best practice" suggests that we can stop thinking about new and better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these Sass variables and adjust them accordingly.

```
$h1-font-size: emCalc(44px);
$h2-font-size: emCalc(37px);
$h3-font-size: emCalc(27px);
$h4-font-size: emCalc(23px);
$h5-font-size: emCalc(18px);
$h6-font-size: 1em;
```

They documented this very well

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/type.html